# Global variable from JSON DataStore

Tags: extjs

I would like to declare a global variable that takes value from DataStore and display its value in the alert Window.

```
var params = 1;

var storeTeacher = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
       id: 'IDstoreTeacher',
       url: 'school.php',
       method: 'POST',
       baseParams:{task: "LABEL",
                   parametar: params},
       root: 'rows',
       fields: 
              [{name: 'NameT', type: 'string', mapping: 'Teacher_name'}],
       autoLoad: true   
    });

var TeacherName;

storeTeacher.load({ 
       scope: this, 
       callback: function (records, operation, success) { 
                   TeacherName = storeTeacher.getAt(0).get('NameT');
              }
});


alert(TeacherName);
```

But, only thing I get is the alert Window that says: undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alert(TeacherName);` call is being executed before the callback on your `storeTeacher.load` callback is being executed.

If you put the `alert(TeacherName)` in the callback function it will populate your TeacherName properly and show correctly in the alert:

```
storeTeacher.load({
    scope: this,         
    callback: function (records, operation, success) {                     
        TeacherName = storeTeacher.getAt(0).get('NameT');
        alert(TeacherName);   
} });
```

This behavior is expected.